# Создайте программу, которая будет увеличивать или уменьшать размеры блока с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции, click, addeventlistener

Создайте программу, которая будет увеличивать или уменьшать размеры блока — левая верхняя точка блока всегда будет находиться в начале страницы (в левом верхнем углу),
а другая точка будет задаваться курсом мыши. При щелчке мышью блок должен заполнить область от начала страницы до текущего положения курсора.

```
<style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        div {
            background-color: blueviolet;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="colorBlock"></div>

    <script>
        colorBlock.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            //???
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Вешайте событие на на div, а на document. [События мыши можно посмотреть здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .color-block {
            background-color: blueviolet;
            height: 1px;
            width: 1px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="color-block"></div>

    <script>
        const colorBlock = document.querySelector('.color-block')
        document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            colorBlock.style.height = event.pageY + 'px'
            colorBlock.style.width = event.pageX + 'px'
    })
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]